# Creating a select query that fetches records according to multiple variables

Tags: php, sql

I need to create a select query which fetches records according to multiple variables
like:

```
<?PHP

@$task=$_REQUEST['task'];
@$Country=$_REQUEST['Country'];
@$City =$_REQUEST['City'];
@$MosqName =$_REQUEST['txtMsqName'];
@$PostCode =$_REQUEST['txtPostalCode'];

$sql_serch="SELECT  Country="."'".$Country."'", " City="."'".$City."'"." FROM job_mosqu";
?>
```

It is not working.

Comment: You should be sanitising these `Request` items in some way before concatenating them into a query to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to escape your input!  **NEVER** put user-inputted variables (such as those from `$_REQUEST`) directly into SQL queries.  Either use parametrized queries or escape the input using either `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysqli::real_escape_string` or `PDO::quote` depending on what you're querying with...

Some reading on the subject:

1. [PHP MySQL by example](http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_MySQL_by_examples-193.html)
2. [StackOverflow question on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)
3. [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

And to answer your actual question, use the [`WHERE` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

```
SELECT * FROM job_mosqu WHERE Country = ? AND City = ? ...
```

There's plenty to read out there on using the where clause, just do some searching if you're not comfortable with it...

1. [Tutorial on WHERE in mysql](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp)
2. [Another Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)
3. [And yet another](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlwhere.php)

Comment: i found this and it working fine 

$sql_serch="SELECT * FROM job_mosqu WHERE Country='".$Country."' AND City= '".$City."' AND Zip = '".$PostCode."' AND MosqueName = '".$MosqName."'";

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `AND`

```
SELECT * FROM job_mosqu WHERE Country='$country' AND City= '$City'
```

Etc...

Comment: Fun fact: You can use parenthesis to set precedence on your and/or operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM job_mosqu WHERE Country='$country' AND City= '$City' AND task = '$task' AND $MosqName = '$MosqName';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect query. It is very bad query. May be you want next?

```
$task=$_REQUEST['task']; 
$Country =$_REQUEST['Country']; 
$City =$_REQUEST['City']; 
$MosqName =$_REQUEST['txtMsqName']; 
$PostCode =$_REQUEST['txtPostalCode'];

$sql_serch="SELECT `Country`, `City` FROM `job_mosqu` WHERE `City`='" . $City. "' AND `Country`='" . $Country . "'";
```